# a jquery plugin to upload a single file 'silently'

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

In my web app,I need to upload a single file when a user selects that file and stay on the same html page.I am looking for a non-flash solution which probably uses `jquery`.and something which works on firefox.

By googling,I came across many plugins,most of them using elaborate html pages for showing `input widgets / upload status indicators` etc.I need something which I can use like this,using ajax.

mypage.html

```
<input type="file" id="myfileselect" > </input>
```

myjs.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myfileselect').change(function(e){
       //upload the file somehow
   }

});
```

Is this possible?Can someone illustrate how I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ or this link http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/ ? Google is your friend :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this plugin in all my projects. Once the user selects the file, you simply call

`$('#yourForm).ajaxSubmit()`

and it will asynchronously upload your file.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

In your case, you would do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="file" id="myfileselect" > </input>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //set the options here
    var options = {
        url : 'yourScript.php',
        method : 'post'
    };

   $('#myfileselect').change(function(e){
       $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit(options);
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..but I am not using php..my app is based on django/python

Comment: It does not matter what language your backend script is coded in. You simply POST the file to whatever server-side script you have set up to receive the file.

Comment: I think the file-data from javascript will not be available to the `request.FILES` at the django view